# I host a website through godaddy. I get an error message (error on php line 7) when I try to access the site

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I host a website through godaddy. It was working fine two days ago but now I get an error message when I try to access the site. I do not know who originally wrote the script for this site so I cannot ask that person for help, hence why I am desperate and asking for help here.

Below is the error can anyone help me out? I've searched high and low for answers and cannot find anything.

```
Warning: mysql_pconnect() [function.mysql-pconnect]: Access denied for user 'newportstorm'@'173.201.196.208' (using password: YES) in /home/content/31/6949531/html/Connections/NewportStorm.php on line 7

Fatal error: Access denied for user 'newportstorm'@'173.201.196.208' (using password: YES) in /home/content/31/6949531/html/Connections/NewportStorm.php on line 7
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about that error message?

Comment: I don't know anything about script or php so I don't know how the error originated or what I need to do to fix it

Answer (score 0):

your database user 'newportstorm' dont have any permission granted to connect mysql server running on '173.201.196.208' (mysql server user management), or you are passing a wrong password for the db user in your mysql_connect function parameters. (on NewportStorm.php line 7)

Comment: I did change my password, would I need to go in and change the password to the new one?

Comment: then you need to change to in the apps configuration (to be used in NewportStorm.php line 7 on connect function). Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to change your DB password. Look in the file stated in the error message, there will be something like mysql_connect or equal. The 3rd parameter is the password, change this to the new one.